# Using AWS SDK v3 with aws-xray-sdk and getting segment.addNewSubsegmentWithoutSampling errors when deployed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs, aws-xray

package versions:

- @aws-sdk/client-*: 3.398.0
- aws-xray-sdk: 3.5.1

I have been writing custom helper classes for AWS services and have the following configuration:

Base Helper Class (common funcs and what not)

{{AWS_SERVICE}} Class Extends Base Helper

like so:

```js
export class S3Helper extends BaseHelper {
    private client: S3Client;
    private httpHelper: HTTPHelper;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of S3Helper.
     * @param logger {ILogger} - Injected logger.
     * @param client {S3} - Optional injected S3 client. If not supplied, a new S3 client will be created.
     * @param options {ClientConfiguration} - Optional S3 configuration.  Only used if the service parameter is not supplied.
     */
    constructor(logger: ILogger, client?: S3Client, options: S3ClientConfig = {}, httpHelper?: HTTPHelper) {
        super(logger);
        this.client = client || AWSXray.captureAWSv3Client(new S3Client(options));
        this.httpHelper = httpHelper || new HTTPHelper(logger);
    }
}
```

All Lambda functions have xray tracing enabled so that isn't my issue. When deployed and running on Node 18.x, here's the issue when (in this case) reading from Param store.

```json
{
    "level": "ERROR",
    "msg": "segment.addNewSubsegmentWithoutSampling is not a function",
    "errorName": "TypeError",
    "errorMsg": "segment.addNewSubsegmentWithoutSampling is not a function",
    "errorStack": "TypeError: segment.addNewSubsegmentWithoutSampling is not a function\n    at /var/task/index.js:6948:30\n    at /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-content-length/dist-cjs/index.js:26:16\n    at /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-serde/dist-cjs/serializerMiddleware.js:13:12\n    at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-logger/dist-cjs/loggerMiddleware.js:6:22\n    at async SSMHelper.GetParameter (/var/task/index.js:890311:20)\n    at async Runtime.handler (/var/task/index.js:906957:27)"
}
```

I've tried multiple different versions of AWS SDK, XRAY SDK, different combinations, all that. Everything worked when old legacy code was on AWS SDK v2 and used `captureAWSClient`

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure that all lambda layers containing the AWS X-Ray Node SDK are using the same version (>= 3.4.0 where this API was introduced). See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-node/issues/544) for more details and resolution for this issue.